# Response Status: 200 OK but Response body is Null in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

For one of my Requests in jmeter, I am getting Response code as 200 OK but Response body is NULL.
Due to this "Response Assertion" is failing since we are expecting Response to generate.
Here i am unable to get as to why the status code is 200 even though Response body is null.

[Sampler result showing Response status as 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8rcI.jpg)

[Response Data SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw33O.jpg)

[Response assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmi7B.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) to be [200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) and not interested in the body - amend your Response Assertion configuration as follows:

- Fields to Test: `Response Code`
- Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
- Patterns to Test: `200`

This way your assertion will pass.

[image]

Check out [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) article for more information on using Response Assertion to conditionally mark [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as passed or failed

---

If you expect the request to return some body data - then assertion failure is correct and I can think of the following options:

1. You're sending a malformed request hence not getting a response, cross check the request with the API contract or with the other API testing tools like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)
2. There is a bug in your application. Status code 200 doesn't necessarily mean success and vice versa
3. If the situation happens only under the load it might be the case you found the [bottleneck](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/wp-rapid-1.pdf)